# obtaining habitat suitability layer from step selection function (iSSF) from the amt package in r

Tags: r, connectivity, coefficients

I am performing a connectivity analysis on cheetah GPS data. Using the amt package I am supposed to be able to get a habitat suitability layer. With a c8 transformation I will obtain the resistance to movement layer, which can be used in UNICOR for a connectivity analysis. Now I am struggling figuring out how I can use the output from the fit_issf function from the amt package in r.

I first created tracks and extracted the covariates in order to run the following simple iSSF
#simple iSSF
m1 <- ssf_dat %>% fit_issf(case_ ~ bio1_end + bio4_end + bio12_end + bio15_end + slope_end + hfp_end + landcover_end + sl_ + log_sl_ + cos_ta_ + strata(step_id_), model = TRUE)

[output iSSF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2XBE.png)